# VS 2012 stops debugging right after start

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have got Windows 8 a few days ago and now there is a strange behavior:
(Asp.net Application using local IIS and IE as Testbrowser)
When i start the application with debugging, VS starts the build as it should be. The build completes without any errors and VS is switching to the "debug mode" (changing toolsbars, Windows, ...).

But right after the browser (IE) pops up, it gets closed again and the debugging stops.
After a few tries (2-4) suddenly everything works normal.

Is there someone who can give me a hint what the problem can be?
Or, even better, knows how to solve it? =)

UPDATE: I'm using IE11

UPDATE: I have found a message in the "Output" window "The program '[9688] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1073741790 (0xc0000022)." Google does not show me any usefull hint... is here someone knowing this errorcode?

Comment: Ensure you have a startup project set. Ensure you have a startup page set.

Comment: Both set. The compile is successfull and the browser is showing up for nearly a second...

Comment: as a workaround, you could attach to the w3wp process (assuming that you're running in IIS) rather than hitting F5, which would take the dependency off of IE.

Comment: Try to move temp files to a RAM disk. In web.config: <compilation tempDirectory="R:\Temp\">

Comment: sure... but i want to solve this problem and use the "normal" and "easy" way ;)